# Translate assets-library:// scheme to file:// in order to share to instagram while keeping metadata

Tags: ios, file, instagram, alassetslibrary, uidocumentinteraction

I'd like to find a way to share assetURL straight to instagram using UIDocumentInteraction while keeping embedded metadata in the asset representation (It turns out that trying to load the asset as an image representation makes you loose any metadata you wanted to transport to instagram, including EXIF-like metadata).

I tried to explore a simple way, as follows:

```
self.docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:assetURL usingDelegate:self];
```

But it came into dead-end, I'm stuck with the following error message:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme assets-library.  Only the file scheme is supported.'`

Given that, I'd like to find a way to translate asset-libray:// scheme into absolute file:// scheme.

Any idea, or different approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the `defaultRepresentation` of the asset then you can get the `metadata` dictionary which contains all of the EXIF data. Once you have the image and the EXIF data you can use `AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation` to get the data that you will store / share.

Comment: How would you get a CMSampleBufferRef to use with jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation from a representation (alternatively from an UIImage) ?